# Memory Profiling for a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to run a memory profile on a Windows Store app, and I'm getting a confusing error message.

Here is the procedure I'm following:

1. Click ANALYSE -> Profiler -> New Performance Session
2. The Performance Explorer pops up.  In the Performance Explorer, right click on the session I've just created (called "Performance1 (Sampling)" and choose "Properties".
3. On the General Tab (the default), go to the ".NET memory profiling collection" group box, and choose "Collect .NET object allocation information" and "Also collection .NET object lifetime information" checkboxes.
4. Exit the Properties window.
5. Right click on the "Targets" icon under the Performance1 session, and choose the "Add target project" option.
6. Choose the startup project from the "Add Target Project" dialog and click OK.
7. Right click on the Performance1 session icon, and choose the "Start profiling" option.

The project builds, and an error dialog pops up, saying "Windows Store apps may only be profiled in Sampling or Instrumentation modes."

Repeating the procedure without Step 3 does not produce an error message.  I assume that this means that the "Collect .NET object allocation information" and "Also collection .NET object lifetime information" options are seen as additional modes, which aren't available for Windows Store apps.

Does this mean Visual Studio 2013 does not offer a way to detect memory leaks in Windows Store apps?